# Is it possible to configure multiple Apache WSGIAlias'es under same VirtualHost?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost, django-wsgi

I currently have an SSL configuration file in apache to serve my django project. Currently that setup looks something like:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#setup of paths to SSL file, default dirs, etc

#
# config for main django site
#
WSGIScriptAlias /v1 "C:/sites/mysite/v1/django.wsgi"
WSGIPassAuthorization On
<Directory "C:/sites/mysite/v1/myAppName">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

That works. However, I'd like to add a staging/test URL path (but different code directory) to the same server and reuse the existing certificate. However, if I tweak the above code and restart the server, hits to my /demo/ site are throwing an internal server error, although calls to the main django site continue to work:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#setup of paths to SSL file, default dirs, etc

#
# config for demo django site
#
WSGIScriptAlias /demo "C:/sites/demo/django.wsgi"
WSGIPassAuthorization On
<Directory "C:/sites/demo/myAppName">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# config for main django site
#
WSGIScriptAlias /v1 "C:/sites/mysite/v1/django.wsgi"
WSGIPassAuthorization On
<Directory "C:/sites/mysite/v1/myAppName">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

How can I configure Apache to have two different code directories both respond depending on changes to the WSGIScriptAlias path passed on the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Go read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

though as take heed about how to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. You may be hitting that issue.

Do though update your question to say though what URL you are trying to access and whether you are getting an Apache 404 page or a Django one.

BTW, both of your Directory blocks are wrong as they use the wrong directory. Are these the actual configs you are using or have you doctored it to protect real values?

Comment: Yes, the directory blocks are rewritten to obscure real configuration details but your question made me take a second look. I removed them and *tada* things worked as before. 

I added the WSGIScriptAlias path as described in your article. I can now access the demo site in the browser but its throwing 'AssertionError at XXXXX No Exception supplied'. Reading deeper into your link, I believe this might be because of leaky environmental variables (?). However, when I attempt to add the WSGIDaemonProcess command to the config, as shown, the Apache service refused to start.

Comment: Hmmmm - answering my own question in regards to WSGIDaemonProcess, it appears that it isn't supported as part of the mod_wsgi on Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882605/django-apache-windows-wsgidaemonprocess-alternative

Comment: Following the advice in this Stackoverflow thread ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479239/running-two-django-apps-on-apache-with-mod-auth-sspi-and-mod-wsgi ) got me unstuck. Still needs additional testing, but at least content is flowing to the screen.